# CMake: PASS_REGULAR_EXPRESSION for stderr

Tags: testing, cmake, ctest

I would like `PASS_REGULAR_EXPRESSION` to also check `stderr`. Is it possible? I tried the following:

```
add_test(NAME test COMMAND executable)
set_tests_properties(test PROPERTIES
  WILL_FAIL true
  PASS_REGULAR_EXPRESSION "I was printed to stderr"
)
```

but it doesn't work since `PASS_REGULAR_EXPRESSION` checks only `stdout`. I tried to redirect `stderr` to `stdout` with:

```
add_test(NAME test COMMAND executable 2>&1)
```

But it doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 0):

`PASS_REGULAR_EXPRESSION` does check `stderr`, but it causes the exit code to be ignored. Your example therefore failed due to [`WILL_FAIL`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_test/WILL_FAIL.html): CTest found the regular expression, but it expected not to, and therefore marked the test as failed. After removing `WILL_FAIL`, the tests pass:

```c
// main.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  fprintf(stderr, "I was printed to stderr\n");
}
```

```
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(SO_74340897)

add_executable(executable main.c)
enable_testing()

add_test(NAME test COMMAND executable)
set_tests_properties(test PROPERTIES
  #WILL_FAIL true
  PASS_REGULAR_EXPRESSION "I was printed to stderr"
)
```

Running the tests like:

```
$ ctest
Test project /home/jschulze/tmp/stackoverflow74340897/build
    Start 1: test
1/1 Test #1: test .............................   Passed    0.00 sec

100% tests passed, 0 tests failed out of 1

Total Test time (real) =   0.00 sec
```